# String formatting in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to do binding to a text block in silverlight, but when I'm writing a StringFormat, I'm getting this error-
The property 'StringFormat' was not found in type 'Binding',
Here is my code:

Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=FirstNameTxt, StringFormat='Hi {0}!'}"

(I'm working with Silverlight 4)
And by the way, can anybody recommend me a good sight for learning silverlight??
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[Click Here](http://www.designersilverlight.com/2010/05/28/silverlight-4-binding-and-stringformat-in-xaml/)

Click on the link above u will easily understand how to use string format in silverlight